# How to share a single Array with Multiple blocks and threads?

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to learn CUDA and am trying to complete a simple program. The program looks at a pre-filled array filled with 0,1,2's then tally's up the occurrences of the linked numbers in a shared array (IE how many 00,01,02,10,11,12,20,21,22 combinations). Unfortunately it seems that it only counts 1 of every occurrence and then stops.

The prefilled array has (0,1,0,2,0,0,2,0,1,0)
The expected output should be (1,2,2,2,2,0,0,2,0,0)
The actual output is (1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0)

int a* is the pre-filled array, int b* is the "shared" array of the combinations.

The global kernal is currrently being called with a single block with 10 threads. (Later I would like to change this to be multiple blocks, but I wanted to get threads working first).

Any suggestions?

I've tried sharing the array using **shared** and using __syncthreads but my issue probably requires something else.

```
__device__ int GetIndex(int a, int b) {
    if (a == 0 && b == 0) return 0;
    if (a == 0 && b == 1) return 1;
    if (a == 0 && b == 2) return 2;
    if (a == 1 && b == 0) return 3;
    if (a == 1 && b == 1) return 4;
    if (a == 1 && b == 2) return 5;
    if (a == 2 && b == 0) return 6;
    if (a == 2 && b == 1) return 7;
    if (a == 2 && b == 2) return 8;
}

__global__ void CalculateRecurrences(int *a, int *b) {

    __shared__ int s[TOTAL_COMBINATIONS];
    int e = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        s[i] = b[i];        
    }
    __syncthreads();
    if (e < 10) {
        int index;
        int next = a[e + 1];
        printf("%i %i", a[e], next);
        index = GetIndex(a[e], next);
        s[index] += 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        b[i] = s[i];        
    }
    __syncthreads();
}
```

Thanks in advance. Please let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: Side note: `GetIndex` could be optimized to `return 3 *a + b;`.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: You have multiple threads that can update the same value in shared memory at the same time.  CUDA does not sort that out for you.  You may want to read up on atomics.  Note that on SO, for questions of this form ("why isn't this working?") you are supposed to provide a [mcve].  See item 1 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), not usage of the word "must"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues here.

Recall that every thread is executing the kernel that you've written. So code segments like this one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    s[i] = b[i];        
}
```

Are executed by all 10 of your threads. So all 10 threads are reading and writing all 10 elements of your input array to your shared array. How wasteful! You have 10 threads, and you have 10 elements; you can just tell each threads to work with one of the elements, by replacing the for loop above with:

```
if (e < 10)
    s[e] = b[e];
```

Likewise, you have 10 threads that are all trying to perform the next block of code. You're accessing memory in a way that isn't thread-safe. The simplest solution would be to use atomicAdd instead of +=.

You also have an illegal memory access here; if `a` is defined over the range 0-9, and e is defined over the range 0-9, then `e+1` will exceed the bounds of `a`:

```
int next = a[e + 1];  // Undefined behavior!!!
```

Finally, like above, you have every thread running your final loop to copy the elements of `s` to `b`. You have 10 threads and 10 elements to work with, so you should let each thread operate on its respective index:

```
b[e] = s[e];
```

edit: Put all together your code might look more like this (untested):

```
__global__ void CalculateRecurrences(int *a, int *b) {    
    int e = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (e >= 10) {
        return;
    }

    __shared__ int s[10];

    // All threads read and assign a value to shared memory
    s[e] = 0;  // You're counting; assign 0s everywhere, we don't need array b for this
    // Wait for all threads to complete initialization of shared array
    __syncthreads();

    // Each thread compares its indexed value to the value in the next index
    if (e < 9) {
        int next = a[e + 1];  
        printf("%i %i", a[e], next);
        int index = GetIndex(a[e], next);
        // Since multiple threads may receive same index, need atomicAdd:
        atomicAdd(&s[index], 1);
    }
    // Each thread may be updating different indices than its own.
    // Thus need to wait for all threads to complete
    __syncthreads();

    // Each thread writes its indexed value to global output array
    b[e] = s[e];
}
```

Remember, all threads execute the same kernel code. Thus you should map thread indices to array indices whenever possible, as shown above. I'll also point out that using a shared array probably isn't beneficial in the above example, and you could just initialize and operate on the `b` array directly, but you're probably just using one as an exercise.